# What is it called when authors trade citations?

Tags: citations, terminology, research-misconduct

Citation is one metric of researchers. That is why some of them lend citation to one another. For example, A writes a paper and cites B's work in it, and then B does the same for A, without the citations being relevant to the works.

Is there any word for such academic misconduct? I can think of "citation exchange", but I couldn't find any reference about it.

Comment: In some cases, this is just called "literature review". If you want to publish something new you'd be expected to demonstrate that you are aware of the state of the art in the field. If your field is fairly small, then it may become natural practice that you'll cite some authors and they'll cite you back. This is because you indeed consulted their (and likely improved upon it) and so did they to yours. @Scientist did place one clear line-trespassing example: When you submit a paper and the reviewer demand a citation.

Comment: In some field there is only a small community of researchers so cross-citation is very common and does not constitute "misconduct". Good reviewers in reputable journals will easily spot vanity citations. Researchers who engage in complicated schemes to get unwarranted citations are either incredibly vain or just plain stupid.

Comment: @CapeCode In some countries (e.g. mine), citation indexes are used to establish academic promotions at the national level and, indeed, there are rumours of authors creating citation rings to obtain these advantages. So, no, they're neither stupid nor vain, but fraudulent.Stupid are those who devised such a system.

Comment: Since you call it academic misconduct, let's call it "collusion". Just don't start any witch hunts ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano really? I'd think any half-decent institution would know how to filter out bogus citations or rely on bibliometric sources that do so.

Comment: @CapeCode Really. And the selection according to those parameters is automatic and done at the national level: if you don't reach X citation and H h-index you cannot even apply for a promotion.

Comment: @CapeCode I discussed a bit the system in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/84054/20058) (at the moment, links are broken, I have to update them).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano where do they get the h-index and citation count from?

Comment: @CapeCode Scopus.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano ah Scopus is not too bad at filtering bogus citation, not like Google Scholar. That sounds more reasonable all of a sudden.

Comment: @CapeCode Scopus doesn't filter citations from undetected citation rings, and, thus far, very few have been detected, like in the example I gave in my answer.

Comment: Since many comment mention that two authors citing each other can happen in good faith, I took the liberty of adding a precision to make clear that irrelevant citations are those being considered here.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In addition to the terms suggested by [Scientist](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/120744/20058), another relatively common term is *citation ring*, here *ring* being used with the meaning (from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ring)):

> 7 a : an exclusive combination of persons for a selfish and often corrupt purpose (as to control a market)
>   b : GANG

Here are a few examples of usage of *citation ring*:

> SAGE Publications busts “peer review and citation ring,” 60 papers
>   retracted

([Retraction Watch](http://retractionwatch.com/2014/07/08/sage-publications-busts-peer-review-and-citation-ring-60-papers-retracted/))

> Some other problems of the method were well outlined by Ulrich Korwitz (pp. 107-110): the problems of self-citation and the citation ring [...]

([T. Roper, "Citation Analysis of the Veterinary Literature: A Tool to Understanding Scientific Communication" in *Libraries without Limits: Changing Needs — Changing Roles: Proceedings of the 6th European Conference of Medical and Health Libraries, Utrecht, 22–27 June 1998*](https://books.google.it/books?id=n6jnCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA136&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: This one is new to me and sounds even better, thanks for adding!

Comment: Citation ring has the right _ring_ to it (pun absolutely intended)... any chance you could strengthen the answer with a link to where you noticed that usage, like @Scientist did? I've heard of "citation cartels" he mentions (from the source he links), but not of "citation ring" despite you saying it's relatively common.

Comment: @penelope I've added a couple of examples.

Comment: Awesome, upvoted :)

Comment: @penelope that's a good suggestion indeed! I'll upvote your comment if you upvote mine. ;-)

Comment: [That peer review ring scandal in Taiwan](https://retractionwatch.com/2014/07/14/taiwans-education-minister-resigns-in-wake-of-sage-peer-review-scandal/) caused an Education minister to resign.

Comment: @Scientist Oh my, never realized I might have started an _upvote ring_ on a question about _citation rings_. If we get any more people in on it, we might even call it an _upvote cartel_ :D

Comment: @penelope Well, actually, the main Meta.SE has already many posts about [voting rings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=voting+ring) ;-)

Comment: My impression was that the terms "citation ring" and "citation cartel" suggest more than 2 authors.

Comment: what is the main difference between citation ring and cartels?

Comment: @Monika There's no difference: two possible names for the same thing.

Comment: Also think back on the internet when Altavista ruled or Google was an upstart: Many websites organised themselves into **webrings**, grouping websites around a common topic (often hobby) and linking to each other, for significant boosts to PageRank-like scores. A **citation ring** clearly harks back to that terminology,  with both means and motivation strikingly similar.

Answer (score 27):

I believe this is unethical practice but not "officially" misconduct. There is some ongoing research on this, [elsewhere](https://www.enago.com/academy/citation-cartels-the-mafia-of-scientific-publishing/). 
Some sources call this "citation stacking", while others call it "[citation cartels](https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2016/09/26/visualizing-citation-cartels/)". Mind that these terms were coined for *journals* while they certainly can be applied to authors.

Such citation schemes are an adaptation of other more obvious citation-boosting strategies, such as self-citations or citations demanded by journal editors and reviewers, which are much easier to spot and expose.

Answer (score 16):

These are often referred to as *citation circles*, or *citation cartels*. See [here](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2016.00049/full).

Comment: cartel is very apt, plus 1

Answer (score 3):

In the publishing world, it's called "logrolling".

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrolling)

> Logrolling is the trading of favors, or quid pro quo, such as vote trading by legislative members to obtain passage of actions of interest to each legislative member.

Comment: This is completely unsourced and different to every other answer. Could you add a reference to where it's discussed under this name?

Comment: I believe that is the term used extensively in "Wit's End", about the members of the Algonquin Round Table in the 1920s. The term is also used in the Wikipedia article on that topic, to describe the practice of making favorable mentions of other members' articles.

Answer (score 2):

## Gaming the System – by authors

[Gaming the System: Manipulating the Impact Factor in Research](http://theinstitute.ieee.org/ieee-roundup/members/achievements/gaming-the-system-manipulating-the-impact-factor-in-research) (done by authors in the first quoted paragraph, and by journals in the second quoted paragraph):

> When it comes to research, **many academics tell each other: “You cite my article and I will cite yours.”** Academic departments and even the U.S. National Science Foundation have encouraged collaborative research as something positive, which can be true. However, many researchers routinely add their colleagues’ names to their papers as coauthors in order to make the researchers and their departments look good.
>
> (...)
>
> After an article is accepted by a journal, the author is oftentimes asked to add a few citations in the research article from that particular publication. Many, including myself, can testify to the practice of coercive citations. Authors now understand what is expected and load their articles with citations from the journal to which they are submitting before they are even asked.

## Gaming the System – by journals

[Increasing Citations and Improving Your Impact Factor](https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/increasing-citations-and-improving-your-impact-factor) (for journals wanting to increase their citations):

> At SAGE, we will help you increase article citations **without “gaming” the system** with shortsighted strategies that can only compromise perceived quality. We’ll do this by providing editors with the tools to make informed decisions about types of articles and topics they might wish to invite, which potential authors to contact for relevant papers, etc. More generally, all our marketing and online activities are developed with the aim of increasing citations.

Comment: *More generally, all our marketing and online activities are developed with the aim of increasing citations.* Part of me just died.