# How was the Doctorate/PhD title awarded in Italy in the 1980s and now? when can someone apply for Post-doc?

Tags: postdocs, physics, degree, italy

One of the top Italian research centre for applied physics, the Area Science Park located in Trieste, just elected its new president.

The president's CV can be found here:
https://ginko.unipg.it/ws/sitopersonale/cv.php?humanid=caterina.petrillo&tipo=EV

By reading it, I discovered she got her Physics degree in 1984, starting in 1985 a post-doc bursary at an Italian institution.

Is it still possible to apply for post-doc bursaries&fundings in Italy without having completed a PhD?

Comment: You ask two questions in the title, and a third, different question in the body of your post. In which one are you really interested?

Comment: I suspect that, worldwide, there are a lot of top research institutions in which the top person is an effective administrator, not a scientist/researcher. And, conversely, lots of top researchers wouldn't want such a position and might not be very effective in the main task: keeping the lights on.

Comment: @Wetenschaap in the three of them, since they are not independent one from the other.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: PhD, post-doc etc are just (more or less correct) translation of Anglo titles, which themselves can vary a lot even now even in Anglo-Saxon countries. Most probably she translated a non-tenured research position/fellowship as post-doc equivalent, due to lack of better term.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist can you refer to a rule about this request?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once."  You have three distinct questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has more than one question asked.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I split the questions and now one of the split question:
https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/165923/128758
 has been closed because it has already been answered here.

Comment: EarlGrey, you should first _edit_ this question so that it contains just one question; then post another question (not two), with the second one. If you edit this to contain just one question, I'll then reopen the other.

Comment: @EarlGrey "I split the questions"  No you did not.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist well, let me know how I should procede:
1) delete this question, so the useful answers are lost and the kind answerers have to answer again to the new questions (why should they? do they have infinite time?);
2) edit this question, so the answers does not make sense anymore;
3) ?

what-I-did)
I splitted the questions, into 2 new questions, so google searches are more efficent, "one question one answer" as per the rules you pointed. I will wait, let others chip in, then I will copy there the useful parts from the answers given here. Or?

Comment: @EarlGrey I explained what you have to do in the above: edit this post so that it contains just one question, possibly aligned with Federico's answer, so that we can salvage one of the answers. Then, edit one of the other posts (just one) so that it contains the other question. At that point, I'll reopen that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The doctorate in Italy (*dottorato di ricerca*) was officially instituted [in 1982](https://www.gazzettaufficiale.it/do/gazzetta/downloadPdf?dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=19820920&numeroGazzetta=259&tipoSerie=FO&tipoSupplemento=SO&numeroSupplemento=57&progressivo=0&estensione=pdf&edizione=0), and the first courses started in 1983, so it was definitely not a common thing in the 1980s. People even got full professor positions without having one (since it did not exist).

Post-secondary education was not standardized across nations then like it is today; Italian scientists did their first research experiences with other research contracts, 'assistantships' (*assistente*) and other early-career positions that just weren't formally a PhD and did not end with discussing a thesis.

Regarding that CV, the most likely explanation is that "post-doctoral fellowship" is a liberal translation of the name of the Italian position she held. Note, though, that another non-standard practice of Italian academia is that people can legally be called *dottore* as soon as they get *any* university degree, even a 3-year bachelor. (although in the 1980s university degrees came after a single 4- to 6-year course, which was roughly equivalent to a BSc+MSc course with today's standards). So maybe in the eyes of the translator that position was "post-doctoral" because she was already a *dottore* (although not a *dottore di ricerca*).

As for your last question, it depends on the exact kind of position, but for instance I think you can still apply for a RTD-A (non-tenure-track assistant professorship) without a PhD [EDIT: not anymore since 2017; thanks @MassimoOrtolano for the correction].

Comment: It is somewhat noteworthy that one single special-statute institution, the Scuola Normale Superiore, started their equivalent tertiary course, *perfezionamento*,  much earlier than that (I don't know exactly when, but surely as early as [1930](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/marino-gentile_%28Dizionario-Biografico%29/)). This course is now officially equivalent to a *dottorato*, since 1989.

Comment: About your last paragraph: afaik, it is mandatory by law to have the PhD also for RTD-A positions. Probably, the only position where you can apply without a PhD is the _assegno di ricerca_ of type B.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You are right, I have double-checked, and it seems that the PhD requirement has been added in 2017. It used to be possible, though.

Answer (score 7):

About your last question, let me add something to [Federico's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/165689/20058). Unless you are a lawyer, and I'm not one, in Italy it is frequently difficult to properly navigate and understand the constraints imposed by the law but, as far as I understand, both the RTD-A and RTD-B positions<sup>1</sup> require a PhD or equivalent title<sup>2</sup>. These are the current entry points if you want to aim at a tenured position.

Probably the only position that in Italy does not require a PhD is the *assegno di ricerca di tipo B* (the *tipo A*, instead, is a post-doc position), which is the typical way used to hire someone who has finished the standard three-year PhD period but hasn't yet defended the title. But if you don't have a PhD, you cannot go beyond this, and this position cannot be turned into a permanent one. Without a PhD you're also quite at risk of not being selected if someone with a PhD applies too.

<sup>1</sup><sub>See [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/46009/20058) and [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/159713/20058) for a more detailed description of these positions.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>If you open a *bando* (the application rules), you will likely find that the first 1-2 pages just list the relevant laws, decrees and university regulations on which the *bando* is based, and it's a daunting task to trace back the origin of a certain constraint.</sub>